# Shiny-logs-error-there is no package called 'tidyverse'

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I used shiny output in rmarkdown to create an interactive document and was able to see local html file but when trying to publish it to `shinyapps.io`, I get an error message:

> Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

I checked the logs in the `shinyapps.io`, I see the following error:

> Warning: there is no package called "tidyverse"

Please help me with resolving this issue so that I can create an interactive document with shiny+rmarkdown

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Have you installed the tidyverse package?

Comment: Make sure you are using an updated version of the package.

Comment: Do you have a call to `library(tidyverse)` in your app?

Comment: I think the updating of the tidyverse package helped. Now I am able to run the rmarkdown and got to publish in shiny. Thank you Chabo